# subtract between last cell from a column and last cell from another column, and put the result in a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I need some vba code to subtract between last cell from column B and last cell from column D and put the result in cell N1. The position of last cell, in both columns may variate.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the trick for you. It takes the last cell of both column `B` and `D` and it subtracts their value on the `N1` `cell`:

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim lastBRow As Long
    Dim lastDRow As Long

    lastBRow = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastDRow = Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("N1").Value = Range("B" & lastBRow).Value - Range("D" & lastDRow).Value
End Sub
```